# How to query a text among all fields except using _all field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to query a text among all fields except using _all field in elasticsearch?

```
{  
    "name":"niao",
    "address":"London",
    "email":"xue@gmail.com"
}

{  
    "name":"lia",
    "address":"Hong",
    "email":"lia@gmail.com"
}

{  
    "name":"zhang",
    "address":"Bei",
    "email":"niao@gmail.com"
}
```

I'd like to query records which contain `niao` in arbitrary fields.
The results I want are record 1 and 3.
Though we can query with `_all` field, I don't want to use it.
Are there other ways to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-fields match query, example:

```
curl -X POST \
http://127.0.0.1:9200/mapping/_search \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'postman-token: 05aa4265-8e32-ffaa-43dd-d2299015a5a6' \
-d '{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
        "query":    "niao", 
        "fields": [ "name", "adddress", "email" ] 
        }
     }
   }'
```

Comment: What if I'd like to query among many indices and each index contains many different fields?
I have to list whole fields in the `fields` property of the DSL.